# how can I sort by two identical columns at the same time using SQL?

Tags: sql

for example, I have the following table:

```
name       code1      code2
----------------------------
John         5          3
Kevin        6          4
Mary         3          9
```

I want to sort by code1 and code2 whichever is bigger, so the desire result will be

```
name       code1      code2
----------------------------
Mary         3          9
Kevin        6          4
John         5          3
```

Mary is 1st becuase it has the biggest code (9), Kevin is 2nd because it has the second biggest code (6) and so on...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` which works in most rdbms like Oracle, MS-SQL Server or MySql:

```
SELECT name, code1, code2
FROM TableName
ORDER BY CASE WHEN code1 > code2 THEN code1 ELSE code2 END DESC
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2beae/2/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

For mysql/postgresql/oracle, there is `GREATEST` function.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
ORDER BY GREATEST(code1, code2) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `case` statement in the `order by` clause (among other things). This can be abused quite nicely:

```
order by 
 case 
  when code1 > code2 then code1 
  else code2 
 end
```